# Deleting files in directory / deleting certain directory that is not empty

Tags: python

I am creating a login system and I want to reset the info whenever the system is restarted. I have stored my information in text files in a directory called `accounts`. There are text files and subdirectories in the `data/accounts` directory.

I thought that I can use `os.remove`, but it does not work. So far, I have tried this.

```
import os

def infoReset():
    os.remove("data/accounts/")
```

But it just gives me back an `"operation not permitted"` error. How can I delete the `data/accounts` directory and its contents?

Comment: `os.remove()` will remove a file.
`os.rmdir()` will remove an empty directory.
`shutil.rmtree()` will delete a directory and all its contents.

Comment: from the docs https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html#os.remove "Remove (delete) the file *path.* If *path* is a directory, `OSError` is raised. Use `rmdir()` to remove directories."

Comment: Also, trying to homebrew login systems is usually (basically always) a bad idea. Go with a tested and vetted package if you can possibly find one that works for you.

Comment: To save yourself the headache of manual resource management, consider using a [TemporaryDirectory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryDirectory). See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50691408) below.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a [TemporaryDirectory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryDirectory), which will be automatically removed after you're done with it. This prevents bugs related to your manual and potentially insecure management of a directory.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryDirectory),

> On completion of the context or destruction of the temporary directory object the newly created temporary directory and all its contents are removed from the filesystem.
>
> The directory name can be retrieved from the name attribute of the returned object. When the returned object is used as a context manager, the name will be assigned to the target of the as clause in the with statement, if there is one.
>
> The directory can be explicitly cleaned up by calling the cleanup() method.

Here's an abridged example that applies to your use case:

```
import tempfile

# At the beginning of your program, create a temporary directory.
tempdir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()

...

# Later, remove the directory and its contents.
tempdir.cleanup()
```

Alternatively, depending on how feasible this would be in your project, use a context manager.

```
import tempfile

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdirname:
    # Write files in the directory...
    # ...

    # As soon as your exit this block, the directory is automatically cleaned up.
```

Answer (score 0):

`os.remove()` is for files, not directories. `os.rmdir()` is for removing directories, but only empty directories. To delete a directory and its contents, use `shutil.rmtree()`.

```
import shutil

def infoReset():
    shutil.rmtree("data/accounts/")
```